# Delphi working folder Access Db

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I use Delphi 2010 and adoconnection to connect to Accdb. I save all in c:\Delphi folder but adoconnection when choosing the database reports the error (looks for it on Desktop).
String: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False`
What am I doing wrong? How to set the default working folder?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should point to full qualified DB filename on connection string.

```
ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Delphi\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False';
```

Or if your DB file stored relative to your exe path it should be:

```
ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=' + ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Database1.accdb' + ';Persist Security Info=False';
```

**EDIT** The following statement isn't True, it's my false memories:
*But for note, as my experience you should using Microsoft Access Databases (2002-2003 format)(*.mdb), newest / latest MSAccess DB format isn't supported by current ADOConnection version.*

Comment: @coderbuzz, why do you say which the latest version of MSAccess are not supported by ADO?

Comment: My latest experience with Access Database format .accdb talking* like that, or I'm missing something (select another driver (version) maybe). Just in case, the problem (I forgot exact error message) gone when I use *.mdb format, not *.accdb . CMIIW

Comment: @coderbuzz: Look at your drivers, coz I am using accdb format with AdoConnection without problems. Don't have the code here (am at work) but you basically need to make sure that you select a driver that understands the accdb format. Older drivers of course won't. Access2007 db driver is probably called something like "Microsoft Access 12 OleDB driver" (not sure about the 12 but it should be close)

Comment: Drivers are not the issue. Design time adoconnection looses track of folders. Happens with accdb and mdb. Anyone had this problem?

Comment: @Marjan Venema: Just tried my self a minutes ago, you right, no problem using *.accdb. It's my false 'memories*; some my project deployment (using access db) require to deploy to machine that hasn't office installed, Windows XP. So for safe reason I choose .mdb format :) Thanks for clarify that. (Answer edited)

Comment: @Rawn: Have no idea, not tried yet. I never use design time ConnectionString's value for above reason (locate db file relative to my executable path).